# Rigidbody on UV animations

Tags: unity

I know we need to add rigidbody if we are moving objects.In Unity 5 the performance of moving non rigidbody objects has been increased too.

Though I have doubt over ,Do I need to add rigidbody if I am animating only UVs without moving the object?

Answer (score 1):

RigidBody is for simulating physics.  It is not required to move a gameobject.

```
transform.position += new Vector3(1,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Unity Manual page for colliders](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) is very helpful.

**Rigidbodies** should be used for objects that move often and use physics, such as the main character in a game. You shouldn't use `transform.translate()` or `transform.position` on Rigibodies. Instead, use `Rigibody.AddForce()`.

**Static colliders** have a collider but no rigibody. They should be used for objects that never move, such as walls.

**Kinematic rigibody colliders** have a collider and rigibody with the `IsKinematic` box checked. These are for objects that normally act like static colliders but occasionally need to move.

Note that only certain pairings of these object types will cause a collision. See the table at the bottom of the [Unity Manual page for colliders](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).